# If user enter incorrect date and we have a date in previousDate variable then previousdate should be set on input textbox

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, ngb-datepicker, angular-date-format

- I have input textbox in the angular. In this input text user can enter date manually or using datepicker(ngbDatepicker).
- If user enter valid date then it will assign to previousdate variable.
- If uset enter incorrect date and we have previous date then previous date should set to inputbox on ui side.

Here resetting date is not working.

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAOM.png)

Please refer my code changes on github : https://github.com/akshay-yeole/playground

I'm trying to set previousdate to the input textbox in angular if previous date exists then only.

Comment: All you have to do is bind your previous date variable via ngModel

Comment: It is not working. Please check my code changes on github for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's only add an If in your blur

```
  onBlur(event: any) {
    const date = event?.target.value;
    this.isValidDate = this.validateDate(date);
    if (this.isValidDate) {
      this.previousDate.value = this.model.value ?? '';
    } else {
      if (this.previousDate.value) {
        this.model.value = this.previousDate.value ?? '';
        this.isValidDate = true;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      }
    }
  }
```

NOTE: I forked your code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j9w7qe?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fdate.model.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fcustom-date-parser-formatter.service.ts&title=Angular%20Starter) (It's more easy "play" using stackblitz than github)